# Excel formula to calculate the sum of the first n% visible rows in a filtered column

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Example sheet]

As I stated in the title, I want to calculate the sum of the first n% rows in a filtered column. The total numbers of rows in the column varies due to the filtering options, so my formula must work with different values of n.

For example :
In column A, I have 10 rows that contain values from 10 to 1 ( I sorted them from largest to smallest ).
In column B, I have 10 corresponding rows that contain 2 names: 4 of them contain the value "Tom", six of them contain the value "Jerry". When I filter the whole table and select only the rows that contain the value "Jerry", I want to be able to calculate the sum of the first 20% of the corresponding 6 number values.

Comment: Showing some example data clearly would help.

Comment: Why would you need to filter your data first? Have you thought about doing this directly without filtering, using your criteria?

Answer (score 1):

This could work without any filtering if you want.

[image]

With criteria for column B in `E1` and percentage you looking for in `F1` with the assumption we want to round up the percentage to integers.

So formula in `D1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((B2:B11=E1)*(A2:A11),ROW(A1:INDEX($A:$A,ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(B2:B11,E1)*F1,0)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, without your data, I came up with this, edit to suit your situation...

So, based on the comment, I did a second version:

[image]

The helper column in col C is used with sumproduct to give the result...

Comment: I don't think this is what OP asks, I believe he'll be looking to sum the first 20% of values that correspond with criteria 'Jerry'. In this case 6 values * 20 percent will be 1.2 values. Rounding this up would be the first two values e.g. 9+7 = 16.

Comment: @JvdV hmm, without the OP clarifying the results they expect and not providing their example data you could be correct. if they show data & result I will delete my answer if it is no use.

Comment: Nice one @solarMike

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information, It's my first question here. I have updated my Question, with a spreadsheet picture, to try and clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the percentile function in AGGREGATE with SUMIFS to do what you want:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"Jerry",A:A,">="&AGGREGATE(16,7,A1:A10/(B1:B10="Jerry"),0.8))
```

[image]

---

If you want to use the filter to do the decision:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A2:A10)-1,,1))*(A2:A10>=AGGREGATE(16,7,A2:A10,0.8)),A2:A10)
```

[image]
[image]